# Solving a pair of congruences

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Any ideas on how to solve the congruences
    \begin{eqnarray*}
     p^k &\equiv& 1 \mod q \\
     q &\equiv& 1 \mod p
     \end{eqnarray*}
where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $k$ is a positive integer?

Comment: $(p,q,k)=(2,7,3)$ is one solution. What do you want - all solutions? There might be quite a few....

Comment: Indeed, every Mersenne prime $q=2^k-1$ will give a solution with $p=2$, and it's conjectured there are infinitely many. That gives you at least 47 solutions, anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, for every pair of primes $p,q$ such that $p$ divides $q-1$, we can take $k$ to be $q-1.$ This gives a ton of solutions...

Answer (score 1):

Given any prime $p$, by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $q \equiv 1 \mod p$.  Now you just need $k$ to be any multiple of the order $\text{ord}_q(p)$ of $p \mod q$.  By Fermat's "little" theorem, $\text{ord}_q(p)$ divides $q-1$.